# Fullscreen browser for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, web-browsers

I've got a Raspberry Pi Modell B and I want to run an HTML5 Dashboard on it.

The Pi just needs to display some Canvas Charts in fullscreen. I don't want to see the system bars. The Linux distribution can be very lightweight as I only need to have WiFi, mouse/keyboard and a browser which will be displayed on a TV through HDMI.

Does anyone here have suggestions for such a build? Because I tested Raspbian (Debian Wheezy) with Chromium but unfortunately Chromium cannot run in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried launching Chromium using the `--kiosk` parameter as described in the first answer of this AskUbuntu post?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/358898/how-to-launch-google-chrome-chromium-application-shortcut-in-fullscreen-kiosk-mo

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I do that, it reports: Failed to load NSS libraries. Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

Comment: are you running the command in a terminal emulator on the X11 desktop or just in the command prompt you get at first?

Answer (score 1):

The epiphany browser has a kiosk mode and works great with matchbox-window-manager.  Blog post of how to get it going:
http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/04/rpicframe-html5-kiosk-style-picture.html

create the folder:

```
mkdir ~/.config
```

and here's a bash script on how to do a kiosk with CLI

```
#/bin/bash

# Disable DPMS / Screen blanking
 xset -dpms
 xset s off
 xset s noblank

while true; do
 sudo matchbox-window-manager -use_cursor no -use_titlebar no &
 sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://localhost/index.html
 sleep 2s
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a repository with the node-webkit binary port that runs on Raspbian, tested and working on Raspberry Pi 1 and Raspberry Pi 3 so it is ARMv6 and ARMv7 compatible.

Here you can check it: https://github.com/jalbam/nwjs_rpi

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Node Webkit](http://nwjs.io/). It has a [Kiosk Mode](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode) option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Any hint (More details) to the answer would be very useful!